# How to detect image tampering in java?

Tags: java, image-processing, image-segmentation

I want to create a java code in which I want to detect image tampering like copy paste forgery on the same image and I must use image segmentation to show which part of the image is copy and pasted in other part of image. As I am new to java image processing how to approach from normal image processing to this level.

1. how to read image to pixels in java
2. How to do clustering this pixels to form groups.
3. How to match these groups to get the matching patterns.
4. How to use image segmentation to find the original and copy paste.

I just want a perfect guidance.

Comment: It looks like you have 4 questions here... I suggest you break these up into multiple posts to get better guidance on each one. This is too broad of a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See BufferedImage (for pixel manipulation) and ImagIO (for reading).

Data structures can be optimized, but why not starting with the pixel matrix. In general colour is important, so having color components instead of RGB in one int, is better.

Investigate in looking for yourself: colour artifacts at the border, too strong contrast, missing hairs, wrong shadowing, difference in brightness variance. Do statistics. Moving on a line (y, x1..x2) and areas. Recognize shapes.

Have small test images, unit tests.

*I cannot help more.*

Comment: I think few more lines of explanation helps me as I reading Java Advanced Imaging API: A Tutorial